# exception on sending an automatic email

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

I am trying to send an automatic email in background as a notification for the user,
I am getting a null pointer exception on the following line,

```
Transport.send(message);
```

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Here's my snippet,

```
 public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {   
    try{

    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
    DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
    message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
    message.setSubject(subject);   
    message.setDataHandler(handler);   
    if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
    else  
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   

       //    Log.v("ziad", "wanna send...");
         Transport.send(message);   
      //   Log.v("ziad", "sent...");
    }catch(Exception e){

        Log.v("ziad",e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I added the internet permission as well.

Here's my logCat,

```
05-02 17:57:26.266: ERROR/SendMail(1220): println needs a message
05-02 17:57:26.266: ERROR/SendMail(1220): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
05-02 17:57:26.266: ERROR/SendMail(1220):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
05-02 17:57:26.266: ERROR/SendMail(1220):     at android.util.Log.v(Log.java:116)
05-02 17:57:26.266: ERROR/SendMail(1220):     at zaid.project.EmailSender.GmailSender.sendMail(GmailSender.java:74)
05-02 17:57:26.266: ERROR/SendMail(1220):     at zaid.project.EmailSender.EmailSenderActivity$1.onClick(EmailSenderActivity.java:33)
05-02 17:57:26.266: ERROR/SendMail(1220):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
05-02 17:57:26.266: ERROR/SendMail(1220):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
05-02 17:57:26.266: ERROR/SendMail(1220):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-02 17:57:26.266: ERROR/SendMail(1220):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-02 17:57:26.266: ERROR/SendMail(1220):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-02 17:57:26.266: ERROR/SendMail(1220):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-02 17:57:26.266: ERROR/SendMail(1220):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 17:57:26.266: ERROR/SendMail(1220):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-02 17:57:26.266: ERROR/SendMail(1220):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-02 17:57:26.266: ERROR/SendMail(1220):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-02 17:57:26.266: ERROR/SendMail(1220):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 17:57:27.946: DEBUG/dalvikvm(324): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4K, 54% free 2538K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 254ms
05-02 17:57:32.875: DEBUG/dalvikvm(136): GC_EXPLICIT freed 38K, 51% free 2958K/5959K, external 4845K/5329K, paused 126ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `MimeMessage` needs its text set? Try setting a blank message like so:

```
message.setText("");
```

See if that gets rid of your NPE.

Edit: Actually, I think it may be this line:

```
Log.v("ziad",e.getMessage());
```

Try commenting that out and see if it helps.

Comment: agreed. Most lilely there is another exception at your Transport.send that throws an exception with an empty message, which in turn throws and exception when you try to log it. Try to log e.toString() instead, and call e.printStackTrace()

Comment: when I change it to e.toString(), I get  javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException

Comment: I finally found the bug, it's obvious in the following part,

     public GmailSender(String user2, String password2) {
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.user = user;   
        this.password = password;